# How to ignore letters with accent in a search in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, search, diacritics

I have a SearchBar and I would like to ignore the accents on the letters when I perform the search but I would like to retrieve the word with accent(obviously). My app is in Portuguese so I have a lot of accents in my Array of Strings. I am not sure you guys need more code, if you do please let me know.

Thanks

```
var myArray = [ArrayofInfo]()
var myFilteredArray = [ArrayofInfo]()

let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
myFilteredArray = myArray.filter({$0.name.lowercased().range(of: lower) != nil })
```

Comment: BTW - you can remove your uses of `lowercased()` by also passing in `.caseInsensitive` as an option.

Comment: Thank you very much @rmaddy ! I didn't know the term "diacritics" could be searched for. Just clarifying what I did with your suggestion just for future reference if anyone wants it was. myFilteredArray = myArray.filter({$0.name.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil })